# 5.1 Surround sound speakers not working

Tags: audio, surround-sound

I have my windows pc connect to a Yamaha rx385. But when I test my speakers in windows under sounds, it plays a test tone first out of the left then the center and then the right. But when windows starts to play the test tone at the surround left and right speakers the front speakers are playing it too. How do i solve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you connected to the PC via a single 3.5mm jack? Phono cable? Optical cable? Something else?

Comment: How is your PC connected to the receiver? Is the receiver correctly set up? Does it _really_ produce sound on your center speaker?

Comment: there are a bunch of things to check with this kind of issue, and its quite likely that the reciever configuration is the issue. I'd recommend you start showing us screenshots of the different pages and menus of your audio configuration.

Comment: Im connected with HDMI @spikey_richie